# mysql varchar field not imported correctly

Tags: mysql

I have a csv (500kb) file that contains the entries in the following format:

```
16037549,poetry
598195,historical fiction
22466716,poetry
```

My table is built with the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE `genre`  (
  `book_id` int(11),
  `genre` varchar(200)
)
```

The csv file is loaded with the following `load` command:

```
LOAD DATA local infile '...' into table genre character set 'utf8mb4' fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '\"' escaped by '\"';
```

The problem is `genre` field is not correctly interpreted after import. I cannot do string match like, the following. The result of the query is empty set.

```
SELECT * from genre where genre = 'poetry';
```

However, the following would return the desired result:

```
SELECT * from genre where genre like 'poetry%';
```

It seems there is something around the string that get added to the field during the process of import. I am fairly sure that both `genre` field and `book_id` field stay within the size set by the create table. I encounter the same problem with another file. Both of these fields are at the end of the line.

This problem doesn't exist if I only import a smaller file that contain 10 lines of data from the bigger csv.

I have no idea how to debug the problem. Any better ways to import the csv or any debug tips?

context: I want to upload the file to gcp and the import statement is the format accepted by cloud sql.

Comment: you use comma as seperator and in the data, that will not be possible for mysql to detect it, you need a new field separator or escpe the comma in the data

Comment: There might be trailing spaces at the end of the lines in the text file. Try fixing with `UPDATE genre SET genre = TRIM(TRAILING FROM genre)`.

Comment: It probably is a character at the end of leach line (maybe `\r`?). It could be resolved using `“LINES TERMINATED BY` command.

Comment: As the documentation says: *"For a text file generated on a Windows system, proper file reading might require `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` because Windows programs typically use two characters as a line terminator."* --- If you already loaded the file, fix using `UPDATE genre SET genre = TRIM(TRAILING '\r' FROM genre)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out it is a line termination issue. If you want to upload to cloud sql you need to convert the csv to a linux file. One of the method is using sed:

```
sed -e "s/\r//g" file > newfile
```